# Passagem de Parâmetros de PHP ➝ Javascript ➝PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

Estou precisando passar de  um parâmetros via JSON de uma página PHP   ➝ Javascript ➝ PHP, estou  utilizando o método Ajax do Jquery porém não estou conseguindo, segue trecho código.

✓ **Index.php**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="dateS" name="dateS"  type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></div>
        <label class="col-form-label">entre</label>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input id="dateE" name="dateE"  type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></div>
            <input id="pesquisa" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pesquisar"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

**✓Ajax**

```
function mostrarValor() {
    alert(document.getElementById("data1").value);
}
var datainicio = document.getElementById('data1');
var datafim = document.getElementById('data2');

document.getElementById("pesquisa").onclick = function(e) {
    mostrarValor();
    e.preventDefault();
}

$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/dash/charts/data_acesso.php',
  data: { 'DataInicio': datainicio, 'DataFim': datafim, }
});

$.post('/dash/charts/data_acesso.php', data, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**✓Arquivo que recebe Json para geração de outro**

```
<?php
//Setting Json
header('content-type: application/json');
$datainicio = $_POST['datainicio'];
$datafim = $_POST['datafim'];

//Query por superintendência
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(u.department FROM 1 FOR 12) AS 'department' , COUNT(l.action) AS 'qtdacesso'
FROM mdl_user u
INNER jOIN mdl_logstore_standard_log l ON u.id = l.userid
WHERE action LIKE 'loggedin' AND u.department NOT LIKE '' 
GROUP BY l.action,u.department";

//Execute 
$result=$DB->get_records_sql($sql); 

//Array
$dados = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $dados[] = $row;
    }

print json_encode($dados,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var datainicio = document.getElementById('data1');
var datafim = document.getElementById('data2');
```

Nesse trecho do código, você está pegando o elemento pela ID, mas no seu HTML as IDs dos campos estão diferentes, e como você esta usando jQuery, para pegar o valor de um campo pode ser usado o método .val() http://api.jquery.com/val/ que é muito mais fácil

Fica assim

```
var dateS = $('#dateS').val();
```

A passagem dos parâmetros está correta, porém você não pegou elas corretamente.
Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -4):

Olá ,

**Index.HTML**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input id="dateS" name="dateS"  type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></div>
<label class="col-form-label">entre</label>
<div class="col-3">
<input id="dateE" name="dateE"  type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></div>
<input id="pesquisa" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pesquisar"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**AJAX**

```js
$("#pesquisa").click(function(){

           var datainicio = $("#dateS").val();
     var datafim =  $("#dateE").val();

            jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/dash/charts/data_acesso.php',
    data: {'DataInicio' : datainicio ,'DataFim' : datafim ,},
    success: function(data)
    {
         console.log(data);
    }
   });




}
```

**Arquivo PHP que recebe o Json**

```html
<?php
//Setting Json
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$datainicio = $_POST['DataInicio'];
$datafim = $_POST['DataFim'];

//Query por superintendência
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(u.department FROM 1 FOR 12) AS 'department' , COUNT(l.action) AS 'qtdacesso'
FROM mdl_user u
INNER jOIN mdl_logstore_standard_log l ON u.id = l.userid
WHERE action LIKE 'loggedin' AND u.department NOT LIKE '' 
GROUP BY l.action,u.department";

//Execute 
$result=$DB->get_records_sql($sql); 

//Array
$dados = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $dados[] = $row;
    }

print_r(json_encode($dados));
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Por quê não aproveita e explica o que você fez? Qual era o problema no código da pergunta e como resolveu?

Comment: Como "espera ter ajudado" sendo que você só colou código? Considere dar uma explicação para o autor da pergunta, uma vez que perguntas feitas no site não visa resolver apenas o problema do autor da perguntas, mas qualquer um que esteja procurando e caia nessa página.

Comment: O código Ajax executa assim que for efetuado o click no elemento pesquisa (só fiz de uma maneira mais simples); no php você usa header(json) porem quando vai enviar a informação você usa json_encode, ou seja, o texto deve ser header(text/plain)  para a conversão;